# Run a R buildpack for Shiny app and a JavaScript buildpack for assets on Cloud Foundry

Tags: javascript, r, heroku, shiny, cloud-foundry

Is it possible to use multiple buildpacks for an app on cloud foundry, a R buildpack for Shiny app and a JavaScript buildpack for assets, using something similar to [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi)? I am rather new to cloud foundry but am trying to deploy a Shiny app on CF while leveraging other JavaScript-based services.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there's no built-in support for multi-build packs, however, it's something that is on the horizon.  You can see more about the proposal here.

http://cf-dev.70369.x6.nabble.com/cf-dev-Proposal-for-supporting-the-application-of-multiple-buildpacks-to-a-CF-app-tp6027.html

In the meantime, there is multi-build pack, build pack that you to simulate some of what's being proposed.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/multi-buildpack

Instructions for usage are on the Github site, but here are the rough instructions.

1. Add a file `multi-buildpack.yml` to the root of your app.
2. In that add your list of build packs to run.
3. The last build pack to run will decide the start command.
4. It doesn't work with system build packs, you have to list URLs to build packs.

Ex: multi-buildpack.yml

```
buildpacks:
  - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/go-buildpack
  - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ruby-buildpack/releases/download/v1.6.23/ruby_buildpack-cached-v1.6.23.zip
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I am aware of `multi-buildpack` and have used it successfully on other apps. I think my question is more geared toward R folks and how to make a Shiny app play nicely with other services.